# Can't convert object into a string

Tags: php

I want to output the results of a query in text on a page so I can see what it looks like. Problem is that I am receiving errors if I use an echo like I did below or even use a print.

The error I am receiving is something about not being able to convert an object into a string

My question is what is best way to output query results on the page?

Below is the code:

```
$answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (Answer) 
    VALUES (?)";

      if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }  

    $insertanswer->bind_param("s", $_POST['value'][$i]);

        //$insertanswer->execute();

        echo $insertanswer;

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertanswer->close();
```

Comment: you're not trying to output the results there, you're trying to echo a pdo object. what exactly were you hoping for with this?

Comment: Here's a PDO guide. You might be looking for a way to check affected rows or something since that query above is an insert. http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: PDO is nice, but he is using the [MySQL-Improved driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), not PDO.

Comment: You can echo and print objects that have a `__toString` method that returns a string, but I don't think that's what you actually need here. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't outputting the query result. It appears that you are trying to output the query itself.

However, `$insertanswer` is an instance of [mysqli_statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php). This class does not appear to offer access to the query.

That is why you cannot print it as a string. It isn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to type cast it using the string. for instance you declare a variable to hold the resultant conversion, like $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer ((string)Answer)) 
    VALUES (?)";
or you may type cast the assigned variable thus:
(string)$answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (Answer) 
    VALUES (?)";
 depending on how or where you need your result.

Answer (score 0):

Couple items.  On your binding, you'll want to assign $_POST to a variable first.  I see you have an counter there, but don't see where you are iterating over any thing.  I'll assume you can assign the $_POST['value'] to a scale variable.

```
 $input = $_POST['value'];
```

Then INSERT returns true or false and an ID if you have set an auto_increment attribute on your db table column. If so, you can then use

```
 $insertid = $insertanswer->insert_id;
```

However the way you have the statement written, it wouldn't return any value.  Just true or false and an id (if auto_increment attribute is set).